# Is it true that if polynomial $f(x)$ divides $p(x)$, then it also divides $p(x - 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have been trying to solve a problem from the All-Russian Olympiad 2006. It is the following:
The polynomial $H(x) = \left(x+1\right)^n-1$ is divisible by some other polynomial $P\left(x\right)=x^k+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+...+c_1x+c_0$, where $c_i$ are all odd and $k$ is even. It must be proven that $k+1 \mid n$.

I have found a solution on the internet, but since I have a slightly different solution, I wanted to ask whether mine is correct.
Here is my solution:

Reduce $P(x)$ modulo 2. Now $$P(x) = \frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1}$$. Since $P(x) \mid H(x)$, then $P(x) \mid H(x - 1) = x^n - 1$ Note that in $P(x)$ the denominator doesn't matter(sorry, I can't express myself better) so that we get $$x^{k+1} - 1 \mid x^n - 1$$. From here it is a well known fact that $k+1$ must divide $n$. Is my solution OK? If it isn't, can it be fixed?

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ you can't write $\displaystyle P(x)=\frac{x^{k+1}-1}{x-1}$; and I don't understand as you state that $x^{k+1}-1/x^n-1$.

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I wanted to say that if the reduced $P(x)$ divides $H(x)$ then also $(x-1) P(x)$ will divide $H(x)$, and thus we get $(x - 1) * (x^k + x^{k - 1} + ... + 1) = x^{k + 1} - 1 \mid x^n + 1$. Also, I'm interested in this part: "since $P(x)$ divides $H(x)$ then $P(x)$ divides $H(x - 1)$ Can I use this statement?

Comment: Ok, but in this way you prove that $x^{k+1}-1=(x-1)P(x)$ _in_ $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$; you can't state that $x^{k+1}-1/x^n-1$!, or had I mistake some particular? My council is: have you tried to decompose $H(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?